# Reusing Karma generated Unit Test Report by SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, karma-runner

I am using Karma Test Runner on my JavaScript project to generate a Unit Test Report (target/surefire-report/TESTS-karma.xml) but I am unable to make SonarQube import this by setting 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' to 'reuseReports'.

I configured my Maven POM as follows:

```
<sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
<sonar.inclusions>app/**,astCommon/**</sonar.inclusions>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>     
<sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath>
<sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>
<sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
```

(I guess "sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath" is the right property but just to be sure I did include some other properties as well)

What also surpises me is that I do not get a warning when I enter an incorrect path in 'sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath'. I kind of expected 'Reports path not found'. This makes me suspect that SonarQube somehow is not aware that it should reuse the existing report.

Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks and best,
Ronald

Comment: I looked at the code of the JavaScript plugin version 1.5 and could see that the JsTestDriverSensor.class and JsTestSensor.class were removed. I guess this is the result of http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3408. Now I am pretty confused. Somebody has to explain to me why one would not want to import unit test reports.

Comment: What the heck were they thinking? Agreed.

Comment: hi.. were you able to fix this? I have same problem and those properties doesn't seem to work.. I can see code coverage but not the JUNIT unit test report generated by Karma

Comment: It looks like http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJS-239 (Re-introduce import of unit test result) was resolved on 06/Nov/14.